# Why does the stomach ache if you take a brisk walk after lunch or dinner

Tags: human-biology, food, digestive-system

After eating your lunch or dinner, if you take a brisk walk, most of the time your stomach aches. Why does that happen? What happens with respect to the body metabolism?

Comment: Maybe the acid can go to places through the sphincters (because you move) where the epithel is not accustomed to that kind of acids and then it hurts. And also there is more blood while you are digesting in the stomach and the inervation is more sensitive at that time. But I don't have any proof at my hands right now, so only a comment ;)

Answer (score 3):

The reasons for Exercise-related Transient Abdominal Pain are unknown. The current theories are:

- Irritation of the parietal peritoneum, a structure lining the abdominal wall as it rubs against the visceral peritoneum, which lies against it and over the top of the abdominal organs
- Strain on the ligaments that suspend the abdominal organs (however somewhat unlikely as it occurs during swimming

[image: abdominal contents]

It used to be thought that blood was diverted away from the diaphragm during exercise causing pain however that has been found to be incorrect.

See this link: http://www.ausport.gov.au/ais/nutrition/factsheets/hydration/cramps_and_stitch